# I am having problem reading Excel file using OData SSIS component from Share Point

Tags: sharepoint, ssis

as title says I am trying to read the Excel file placed on online **SharePoint** using the OData component in `SSIS`.

I am trying to make an `SSIS` **package** that will update my database in `sql` `server` with the data from that Excel file. I managed to do that when my file is placed locally.

I also managed to see my file using  by adding **/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/** inside target URI, i get an `Share Point` list where one of the components is my excel file, but I can't open it that way.

**Also I need to use credentials to access the SharePoint.**

I would be thankfull for any help :D

Acceptable solution would be to **download** that file first, but I haven't managed to do that either.

Comment: Can't do what you want with OData component, there is no out of box component that will work for this.   You're looking at a 3rd party vendor like KingswaySoft or CozyRoc that have SharePoint connectors, they are not free.   Or roll your own with some sort of custom script component.  We use powershell in separate agent job steps to handle that.

Comment: @TimMylott tnank you a lot for confirming that! Had some doubts about using OData for anything else except SharePoint list. I dont have much scripting experience. Is it hard to write powershell script for downloading excel file from SharePoint.?